# Removing empty data row when gathering all the table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've gathered data on a html table into an array object. There is an empty data row produce. How do i get rid of the data stored on the 0th row. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
$("#checkout").on('click',function(){

$("#table tr").each(function(){
    var currentRow=$(this);

    var col1_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var col2_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var obj={};

    obj.col1=col1_value;
    obj.col2=col2_value;

    arrData.push(obj);
   sessionStorage.myArrData=JSON.stringify(arrData);
});
 console.log(arrData);

});
```

Comment: comeup with your relevant code here so that people can understand your problem and solve it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn’t post any HTML, I’ll take a guess at your problem. You’re trying to gather the values out of that table in the bottom half of your screenshot. You’re iterating over rows in the table and grabbing all values of the td cells. Your first row is a header so it has no `td`s, and instead is just `th`s, which is why your first JavaScript object is just empty strings as opposed to `{col1: “Item”, col2: “Quantity”}`. You should wrap that first row in a `thead` tag and wrap all of the other rows in a single `tbody` tag, to separate the head from the body of the table. Then, you can simply update your selector in your JS to be “table tbody tr”.

I would ask what you’re doing here, because using a form and serializing that into local storage makes way more sense than parsing a table that you built.